# How to use setpixel for negative pixel value in c#?

Tags: c#, image-processing, graphics

When I am doing to get image from pixel by doing this and got error as:

> Additional information:value of "-13" isn't valid.

So please help me.

`bmp.Setpixel(x,y,Color.FromArgb(100,-12,100,100);`

What to do for negative pixel value as above?

Comment: sorry instead of -13 ,it is -12.Value for -12 is not valid .

Comment: Where did you get the negative value from? You can only use values 0 through 255 with the FromArgb function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/at1k42eh(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Actually I am doinh face recognition and I came in the condition where I have to subtract average pixel value from given pixel value. Is there any solution for doing this.

Comment: Assuming your range is [min_in…max_in] you need to map this to [0…255] for each color channel, i.e. out = (in - min_in) / (max_in - min_in) * 255. If min_in and max_in are unrestricted or unknown a good method is to set min_in to the 5th percentile of all your values and max_in to the 95th percentile.

Comment: Ok I will try it and comment u soon .thanx a lot @ckuri

Answer (score 2):

You should do one of two things.

Option 1 is what you appear to be doing now, but with a limit

```
int clampedRed = Math.Max(0, red - average);
// Repeat for Blue, Green  

bmp.SetPixel(x,y,Color.FromArgb(100, clampedRed, ...)
```

Better however would be to not use the average pixel values, as that is going to drive half your image into black. Probably better to "normalise" the image. That means you need to find the MIN and MAX for each channel in the image (or a quartile) and then scale all pixels.

```
int minRed = // Get min in image
int maxRed = // get max in image
int rangeRed = maxRed - minRed
float scaling = 255 / rangeRed;

foreach (pixel in image){
   int normalisedRed = (int)((pixelRed - minRed) * scaling)
   int clampedRed = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(255, normalisedRed));
   // And then use that...   
}
```

Comment: Ok sir.  Actually what I did is .avg=(pixel.R+pixel.G+pixel.B)/3  and this average is my grayscale color. So when doing any_pixel_value_image-avg. I got negative result. I have tried your first one and is improved by little. I will try the second one.

Comment: I did avg. Becoz while converting a image (40*40)pixels into one dimension(1*1600)pixels .I forcely store the value as the average of red,green and blue for each dimension . Is there any solution for store all 3 pixel value into a dimension and then later geting all the pixel value..thanx in adadvance

Comment: @DiwasPoudel - If you want to convert an image into a 1600 value array, I'd suggest you created 3 arrays instead. One array of Red values, a separate Blue array and a separate Green array. To get a particular pixel value then you can use `SetPixel(redArray[101], greenArray[101], blueArray[101])` for instance.

Comment: If you have more detail than that, please ask another question rather than using comments, feel free to comment with a link to it and I'll go have a look.